# jQuery scrollTo or animate do not scroll page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollto

I am trying to do something simple: when the user clicks on a div, the whole page scrolls to a certain location. I have done this before, but somehow this seems to not be working now. I mean, for now I just want *any* scrolling to happen to know that the plugin works.

It's quite simple really: $.scrollTo(500, 500) should be working, but nothing reacts, no error is thrown.

Here is a link to a dummy version of what I am doing: http://jansensan.net/dump/jquery-scrollto-issue/ Simply click on the black div at the bottom right to see... nothing happening. You may also look at the full code: http://jansensan.net/dump/jquery-scrollto-issue/js/global.js.

Is there anything in CSS that could break that functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript says:

```
function scrollToTouts()
{
    // FIXME: whatever I do here, nothing scrolls
    $.scrollTo(500, 500);
}
```

Don't you need to supply the target of the scroll?

e.g.

```
$.scrollTo('#content', 500, 500);
```

or

```
$.scrollTo('body', 500, 500);
```

Comment: yeah, that's what i figured a bit later. odd cuz the examples i found did not have it, but that fixed it indeed.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $('#elementID').offset().top
}, 1000);
```

Replace `#elementID` with the id of the element you want to scroll to with animation.

[Check out the actual implementation by click on Request Quote link at bottom.](http://www.techelitez.com/services)

Answer (score 1):

It seems I was relying on wrong examples, `$.scrollTo("#bottomContent", 1000, {easing:"easeInOutCubic"});` does work, sorry if for some of you this issue was obvious.